# Making a layer to appear at the back

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I am trying to figure out to bring a layer or image that I want to appear at the back without interrupting the one that I have already completed , [image] like the one on the picture , I have created the city and the landscape the thing is I am stuck with the planet and space one , like is there a way to do it?
and I see it in here too [Example](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-spectacular-concept-art-in-photoshop--psd-125)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to create this edit using layers instead. So that you can edit, add or remove layers.

The tutorial you linked to doesn't do that. It repeatedly makes use of "Apply Image" - which is in essence flattening the image as you edit. If you do that, it's going to be very difficult to change it after the fact.

Find a better tutorial which makes use of layers, without applying or flattening the image.

Answer (score 0):

it annoys a bit the disproportionate size of the planet on the right, if there is no option to move it or decrease it at least try to balance the space with nines to the right also

the shadow on the lower ground is very heavy

It's a good job, you're on the right track.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel Acosta, Welcome to graphicdesign.stackexchange. Your entry does not answer the question that was asked. Encouragement is always appreciated (along with a relevant answer to the question.)